# How to change Mailgun http client from symfony/http-client to guzzlehttp/guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, mailgun

I am using the recent version of Mailgun v 3.5.2 that comes with symfony/http-client when you install Mailgun using composer.

I have tried the code below but it is not working.

```
public function send (){
//client   
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
// First, instantiate the SDK with your API credentials
$mg = Mailgun::create('key-****',$client); // For US servers


// Now, compose and send your message.
// $mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com',
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.'
]);
}

}
```

I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Mailgun\Mailgun::create() must be of the type string, object given
```

I have also updated the composer json in mailgun php as seen below

```
{
    "name": "mailgun/mailgun-php",
    "description": "The Mailgun SDK provides methods for all API functions.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Travis Swientek",
            "email": "travis@mailgunhq.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
        "php-http/client-common": "^2.2.1",
        "php-http/discovery": "^1.9.1",
        "php-http/multipart-stream-builder": "^1.1.2",
        "psr/http-client": "^1.0.1",
        "webmozart/assert": "^1.9.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "nyholm/nsa": "^1.2.1",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "nyholm/psr7": "PSR-7 message implementation",
        "php-http/guzzle7-adapter": "HTTP client"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mailgun\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mailgun\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix that error or which is the correct way of changing http client in this version of Mailgun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to set the client in the `create` method, but the method signature expects a url as the second parameter

```
public static function create(string $apiKey, string $endpoint = 'https://api.mailgun.net'): self
```

use the `HttpClientConfigurator->setHttpClient()` instead which gets injected to the contructor of the `MailGun` class

```
public function __construct(
        HttpClientConfigurator $configurator,
        Hydrator $hydrator = null,
        RequestBuilder $requestBuilder = null
    ) {
        $this->requestBuilder = $requestBuilder ?: new RequestBuilder();
        $this->hydrator = $hydrator ?: new ModelHydrator();

        $this->httpClient = $configurator->createConfiguredClient();
        $this->apiKey = $configurator->getApiKey();
        $this->responseHistory = $configurator->getResponseHistory();
    }
```

For example

```
$configurator = new HttpClientConfigurator();
$configurator->setHttpClient(new YourClientImplementation());
$configurator->setApiKey('your api key');

$mg = new Mailgun($configurator);

// Now, compose and send your message.
// $mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com',
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I use this in the code I have posted from my project?

Comment: I have done that now I am getting the error below ```Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Class Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client wasn't found. ```

Comment: please show your code and please add also the error stack

Comment: ```//client   
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$configurator = new HttpClientConfigurator();
$configurator->setHttpClient($client);
// First, instantiate the SDK with your API credentials
$mg = Mailgun::create('key-***'); // For US servers
// Now, compose and send your message.```  It look like the Class Symfony\Component\HttpClient is hardcoded in their classes. I have tried using namespace ```use Class Symfony\Component\HttpClient``` but it is not working yet.

Comment: Because you never use `$configurator` instance ...  don't use the static ::create method, instead set the API key also in the configurator using `setKey()` method `$configurator->setKey('your api key')` .. i adapted my answer again

Comment: It has worked! The method is ```$configurator->setApiKey()``` not ```$configurator->serKey()```. Thank you so much for your help.